# wp.getUsers XML-RPC method is returning only 50 users, how can i get all the users

Tags: xml-rpc, iphone, ios

In my iphone app i am trying to list out all the users using the **wp.getUsers XML-RPC method**, but its not returning all the users, in that blog i have around 180 members , but it has returned only **50 users** in the list,,how can i get all the users ??

i am passing these following 3 parameters **blog_id**, **username** and **password** ,,should i pass **any other parameter** to get all the users in the list?? plas help me out thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to find a XML-RPC method called `wp.getUsers` in `wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php`. Could it be, that you're using an additional plugin that extends the basic behavior of WordPress?

A simple google search for 'wp.getUsers' points me to the the github repo of Max Cutler and the class [wp-xmlrpc-modernization](https://github.com/maxcutler/wp-xmlrpc-modernization). There you have a method [`wp.getUsers`](https://github.com/maxcutler/wp-xmlrpc-modernization/blob/master/class-wp-xmlrpc-server-ext.php#L779) which accepts a `filter` array as 4th parameter.

> The optional $filter parameter modifies the query used to retrieve users.
>        * Accepted keys are 'number' (default: 50), 'offset' (default: 0), and 'role'.

**EDIT**

`wp.getUsers` is using `get_users` / `WP_Users_Query` in the background. Therefore you have to set the `number` parameter to `false` if you don't want a `LIMIT` clause in the SQL statement.

Here is a snippet from the WP_Users_Query class which builts the SQL statement based on the parameters.

```
    // limit
    if ( $qv['number'] ) {
        if ( $qv['offset'] )
            $this->query_limit = $wpdb->prepare("LIMIT %d, %d", $qv['offset'], $qv['number']);
        else
            $this->query_limit = $wpdb->prepare("LIMIT %d", $qv['number']);
    }
```

Unfortunately the `wp-xmlrpc-modernization` plugin filters the parameter `number` with the function `absint` which sanitize a boolean into an integer. You have to edit the plugin and remove/change this filter on [line 808](https://github.com/maxcutler/wp-xmlrpc-modernization/blob/master/class-wp-xmlrpc-server-ext.php#L808).

```
$query['number'] = ( isset( $filter['number'] ) ) ? absint( $filter['number'] ) : 50;
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply @rofflox , ya i had installed wp-xmlrpc-modernization plugin , what should i pass in filter to get all users suppose i dont know how many users are there on the blog?

Comment: i have tried this,,but its returning 50 again..

Comment: @Ravi I've edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you @rofflox it worked fine,,is it legal to edit those plugins?

Comment: @Ravi Of course it's legal, the plugin is released under GPLv2+. The only reason against altering existing code: It is not update safe. Everytime you update the plugin, you also have to alter the code again. You could contact the developer and ask for a fix in the plugin itself.

Comment: hi @rofflox  
do u know how to list comments using xml-rpc methods,,i have tried wp.getComments but it is returning null

Comment: Please create a new question for each topic next time. `wp.getComments` displays only comments from the builtin comments `taxonomy` which is used by the posttype `post`. If you want to display terms of another, custom taxonomy, you have to write your own xml-rpc method. I've just looked in the plugin you're using. There you have a `wp.getTerms` method which you can probably use for this.

Comment: @ rofflox actually i had framed a new question , but no response for that ,,so i asked u,,thax for ur reply , i ill look into it

Comment: @ rofflox  i have tried wp.getTerms but it didnt give me the list of comments , and i planned to write my own xml rpc method to get comments list , but i couldnt do,,since i am into iphone development i dont have knowledge on php,,can u pls share ur code if u have writen any xml rpc method to list comments