# metaWeblog.getRecentPosts is returning nothing in my iphone app

Tags: xml-rpc, iphone

**metaWeblog.getRecentPosts**  is returning nothing in my iphone app, follwong is my  objective c code to call that method,xml-rpc wordpress methods like  **wp.getUsers** are working fine, but the methods which are used retrive  commets,posts(**wp.getComments** ,**metaWeblog.getRecentPosts** ) are returning null

```
NSArray *arrParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"username", @"password", nil];
    NSString *strServer = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://abc.com/xmlrpc.php"] autorelease];         // the server
    NSString *strMethod = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"metaWeblog.getRecentPosts"] autorelease];                        // the method
    XMLRPCRequest *objXMLRPCRequest = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:strServer]];
    [objXMLRPCRequest setMethod:strMethod withObjects:arrParameters];
```

how can i resolve this,,,? is there any method to list the comments

Comment: Please edit your question and format it as good as possible: uppercase/lowercase letters, code tags, etc. Later readers should have a good and easy read too. At least we're not in some chat :)

Comment: **IMPORTANT** Please _always_ add any needed information - For example [that you're using a class from a GitHub library](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59573/385). One user already had invested enough time to find that out - DON'T force others to repeat that task!

Answer (score 0):

The [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) has a filter, where you can add your custom methods:

```
function wpse60127_xmlrpc_methods( $methods )
{
    $methods['newWPSE60127Method'] = 'wpse60127_new_method';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'wpse60127_xmlrpc_methods' );
```

Simply add your own methods there (core methods/functions)  are also allowed.